# Cell validation returns run-time error 1004 if there is selected range in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating a table with vba with 1 cell with validation (just for pop-up comment).
The problem is if I got selected cells that overlap cell where the validation is added it will return error.
If the cells are not selected in the workbook the validation will be added normally.
So what is the problem here?

http://shrani.si/f/11/Eb/4nqLpmU6/capture.jpg

The validation cell is B8 in this case. The error happens at .Add.

Reproducable example:
Select cells that overlap with cell B8 in excel worksheet. Then run this subroutine.

```vb
Public Sub test()
    With Range("B8").Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop
        .InputTitle = "SQL Query time:"
        .InputMessage = "Table generated in xxx milliseconds"
    End With
End Sub
```

Table on which error can be reproduced.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dEXLbnglk6xR_JBJDdgZeYnaoCD3Xok0

Comment: What is `RangeTarget`? Can you share more of your code please?

Comment: The sub is really long and the code is netted with classes. RangeTarget is B8 cell.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is we need a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I edited it and added minimal example.

Comment: I only get that error if B8 already has validation. Selecting cells that overlap with B8 does not throw an error when the code is run initially.

Comment: There is something weird going on because if I add .delete infront of it, it will still throw error. But if I delete the table there is no error...

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce that error, even when B8 is part of a table.

Comment: Please check this file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dEXLbnglk6xR_JBJDdgZeYnaoCD3Xok0

Comment: Works fine for me, Office 365.

Comment: Try this workbook and select the whole column. I tried just with B8 selected or 2 cells including B8 selected and it works. But not if the whole column is selected. Something fishy is going on here. There needs to be certain ammount of cells selected including B8 to reproduce this error.

Comment: Ok can reproduce with the whole column selected.

Comment: I can eliminate the error if I delete the very last row of the table. In fact, I only get the error if a cell in the last row of the table is currently selected. Maybe a bug?

Comment: I guess... it's unexpected behaviour.